# Replacing "&" with "and" in apalike2 bibliography style alongside natbib package and citations

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I am trying to replace "&" with "and" in my bibliography and citations using the `apalike2` style alongside the `natbib` package. I have tried so many solutions given here on texstackexchange but could not successfully get the desired result. I need help changing the "&" with "and". My prblem and desired output is shown in the following picture:
[image: Problem description and desired result]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm,
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    I want this citation \cite{hapa:graphenum} to be \textcolor{red}{Harary and Palmer }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1973})}. I want this citation \cite{Knuth94:TheTeXbook} to be \textcolor{red}{Knuth }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1994})}.This text is quoted from \cite{datta2017latex} should be (\textcolor{red}{Datta\textcolor{black}{,} 2017}).
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \backmatter
    
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{references}
    
\end{document}
```

Below is my references.bib file

```
@book{hapa:graphenum,
    author =     {F. Harary and E. M. Palmer},
    title =      {Graphical Enumeration},
    publisher =      {Academic Press},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1973
}
@book{Knuth94:TheTeXbook,
    author =     {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    title =      {The \TeX book},
    publisher =      {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1994,
    series =     {Computers \& Typesetting A},
    address =    {Reading, MA},
    titlenote  =        {with illustrations by Duane Bibby}
}
@book{datta2017latex,
    title={LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing},
    author={Datta, Dilip},
    pages={465--523},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APA is (in)famous for its usage of & in references. They *do* want it like this, unfortunately. The reason for this desire of making author lists like commercial companies is unknown.

Anyway, if you look into `apalike2.bst` in your TeX system, you will find three occurrences of `\&`:

```
    297                 { " et~al." * }
    298                 { " \& " * t * }    % changed from " and " for names -- BJR 10/5/89
    299               if$

    329                 { " et~al." * }
    330                 { " \& " * t * }    % changed from " and " for names -- BJR 10/5/89
    331               if$

   1018             { " et~al." * }
   1019             { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * } % " and " --  BJR 10/5/89
   1020           if$
```

Line numbers on the left are for references. You see that the original version had “and”, but it was replaced in 1989 by &.

How do you avoid the dreaded &? By not using APA based styles, first of all.

If you really need to use an old bib style such as `apalike2`, make a copy of `apalike2.bst` in your working directory, naming it `apalike2-and.bst`. In the copy, replace `\&` with `and` (keep all spaces intact).

Change `\bibliographystyle{apalike2}` into

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike2-and}
```

run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX and you'll have your “and”.

The third callout about Datta should be `\citep{datta2017latex}`.

Full example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hapa:graphenum,
    author =     {F. Harary and E. M. Palmer},
    title =      {Graphical Enumeration},
    publisher =      {Academic Press},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1973
}
@book{Knuth94:TheTeXbook,
    author =     {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    title =      {The \TeX book},
    publisher =      {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1994,
    series =     {Computers \& Typesetting A},
    address =    {Reading, MA},
    titlenote  =        {with illustrations by Duane Bibby}
}
@book{datta2017latex,
    title={LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing},
    author={Datta, Dilip},
    pages={465--523},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}

\begin{document} 
    
I want this citation \cite{hapa:graphenum} to be 
\textcolor{red}{Harary and Palmer }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1973})}. 
I want this citation \cite{Knuth94:TheTeXbook} to be 
\textcolor{red}{Knuth }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1994})}.
This text is quoted from \citep{datta2017latex} should be 
(\textcolor{red}{Datta\textcolor{black}{,} 2017}).

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2-and}
\bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Note.** I used `filecontents*` just to make the example self-contained and removed all unnecessary packages. You can keep your preamble and general setup, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg! It worked perfectly! No wonder why you over 1 million worth of reputation, you are the best! Out of curiosity, you said `apalike2` is an old style bib style. I would like to explore the most recent bib style used for Harvard phd thesis. I saw that `apalike2` is the one used in the templates as can be seen from `.cls` file of the `Dissertate` package. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, you can check from this template available on Overleaf here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv

Comment: @itc It’s old, but bst files are pretty stable. You may want to have a look at `biblatex`, though

Comment: Thank you very much Professor @egreg. As a result of your comment, I have opened a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653329/how-to-convert-apalike2-bibliography-style-alongside-natbib-package-to-biblatex.