# How to convert apalike2 bibliography style alongside natbib package to biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib, apa-style, harvard-style

## **Problem Description**

This question is emanating from the comment provided by @egreg at [Replacing "&" with "and" in apalike2 bibliography style alongside natbib package and citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653316/replacing-with-and-in-apalike2-bibliography-style-alongside-natbib-package/653320?noredirect=1#comment1628271_653320) who mentioned that the `apalike2` bibliography style is now old. So I am interested in adopting the `apalike2` bibliography style alongside the `natbib` package **but this time using** `biblatex`. **Remarks: In other words, I wish to have this bibliography style in biblatex as suggested by Professor @egreg**. Below is the MWE which is a very nice solution provided by @egreg to my question at [Replacing "&" with "and" in apalike2 bibliography style alongside natbib package and citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653316/replacing-with-and-in-apalike2-bibliography-style-alongside-natbib-package/653320?noredirect=1#comment1628271_653320):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hapa:graphenum,
    author =     {F. Harary and E. M. Palmer},
    title =      {Graphical Enumeration},
    publisher =      {Academic Press},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1973
}
@book{Knuth94:TheTeXbook,
    author =     {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    title =      {The \TeX book},
    publisher =      {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1994,
    series =     {Computers \& Typesetting A},
    address =    {Reading, MA},
    titlenote  =        {with illustrations by Duane Bibby}
}
@book{datta2017latex,
    title={LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing},
    author={Datta, Dilip},
    pages={465--523},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}

\begin{document} 
    
I want this citation \cite{hapa:graphenum} to be 
\textcolor{red}{Harary and Palmer }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1973})}. 
I want this citation \cite{Knuth94:TheTeXbook} to be 
\textcolor{red}{Knuth }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1994})}.
This text is quoted from \citep{datta2017latex} should be 
(\textcolor{red}{Datta\textcolor{black}{,} 2017}).

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2-and}
\bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

where the `apalike2-and` bibliography is simply the `apalike2` style modified at the following line numbers:

```
 297                 { " et~al." * }
    298                 { " \& " * t * }    % changed from " and " for names -- BJR 10/5/89
    299               if$

    329                 { " et~al." * }
    330                 { " \& " * t * }    % changed from " and " for names -- BJR 10/5/89
    331               if$

   1018             { " et~al." * }
   1019             { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * } % " and " --  BJR 10/5/89
   1020           if$
```

## **What I have tried so far**

Following a comment by @Ulrike Fischer, I modified the code though the following issues have arisen (as a result of using `biblatex`):

1. The citations are not hyperlinked which is something I do not like, and
2. The Bibliography generated using `biblatex` is different from the one generated using `natbib` alongside `apalike2`
   I have attached the pictures showing my problems (as a result of using `biblatex`):
   [image: Problem 1] [image: Problem 2]
   and what I am expecting to get (from `natbib` alongside `apalike2`):
   [image: Desired Output 1] [image: Desired Output 2]
   Below is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{hapa:graphenum,
    author =     {F. Harary and E. M. Palmer},
    title =      {Graphical Enumeration},
    publisher =      {Academic Press},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1973
}
@book{Knuth94:TheTeXbook,
    author =     {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    title =      {The \TeX book},
    publisher =      {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1994,
    series =     {Computers \& Typesetting A},
    address =    {Reading, MA},
    titlenote  =        {with illustrations by Duane Bibby}
}
@book{datta2017latex,
    title={LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing},
    author={Datta, Dilip},
    pages={465--523},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm,
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    I want this citation \textcite{hapa:graphenum} to be \textcolor{red}{Harary and Palmer }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1973})}. I want this citation \textcite{Knuth94:TheTeXbook} to be \textcolor{red}{Knuth }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1994})}.This text is quoted from \parencite{datta2017latex} should be (\textcolor{red}{Datta\textcolor{black}{,} 2017}).
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \backmatter
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: natbib and biblatex are incompatible. Either use the one or the other.

Comment: `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` and then read the documentation how to load bib files with biblatex.

Comment: you didn't run biber.

Comment: I have modified the code again, can you please assist? @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: Please note that "Harvard style" generally just means author-year citations. It is not a well-defined complete style like "APA style" or "Chicago style". A variety of different institutions have defined their flavour of Harvard style. So if you say you need Harvard style citations, you need to be much more specific and explain exactly what you need.

Comment: If you're broadly happy with the output you get from `apalike2` and `natbib` I would not be too quick to switch to `biblatex`. Especially if you have very specific requirements that you cannot change and that are already satisfied by your current setup. Many things are easier with `biblatex`, but it is a pain having to recreate an existing output in each small detail. If you are more flexible in what you can accept, `biblatex` is a great solution, though.

Comment: I mean I need the `natbib` + `apalike2` bibliography style be replicated using biblatex. So far I have managed to provide my trial MWE which is under **What I have done so far**. So I need help modifying the `biblatex` code to produce an exact output produced by `apalike2` and `natbib`.

Comment: As I said above, it is theoretically possible to replicate the exact output of your `apalike2` + `natbib` combination with `biblatex`, but it is going to be extremely painful (it is possible to come up with something that looks similar enough, for some reasonably definition of "similar enough", but every single detail will be tricky). So the question is: Do you really need to use `biblatex`? If you're OK with the output `apalike2` gives you (and you seem to be more than that: you insist on it), then I don't really see the appeal of `biblatex` for your use case.

Comment: Noted with many thanks @moewe

Comment: So, I will stick to `apalike2`+`natbib`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `biblatex` is usually thought to be more modern and flexible than BibTeX's `.bst` styles when it comes to style customisations. `biblatex` also offers a few features that BibTeX cannot offer (full Unicode support, sourcemapping, ...).

But if you already have a BibTeX-based setup that does exactly what you need, it is not always immediately obvious that a switch to `biblatex` is the best choice. You cannot use existing `.bst` files with `biblatex`, so you would have to recreate its output with `biblatex`. It can be quite painful to recreate every single detail of that style with `biblatex` - even if `biblatex` allows you to apply a number of modifications to your style fairly easily.

If you have some leeway in what you are prepared to accept and expect to want to use some of the more advanced features of `biblatex` that BibTeX does not offer, a switch to `biblatex` is a great idea. But if you just want exactly the same output you had with BibTeX, the time required to get that right is probably better spent elsewhere.

---

It would go beyond what a reasonably short answer on this site can provide to recreate `apalike2` output with `biblatex`, so let me just mention a few points.

- A number of simple and common `biblatex` customisations are listed in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). Many, many more can be found on this site if you look for the specific details you are after.
- `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,` is generally not the best base for a custom style. APA style is very complex and `biblatex-apa` has to do a lot of work to get it right. That means that the style is much less customisable than for example the standard `biblatex` styles.
- The different extent of the link targets in `biblatex` are a common complaint. There are many questions and answers about them on this site. The best solution for your use case will depend on the style you use. Some relevant links are [hyperlink name with biblatex authoryear (biblatex 1.4b)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15951/35864), [\textcite macro produces "Author (year)" correctly but colours first paren with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537426/35864), [Problem with code for fully linked citations with biblatex-apa when citing the same name twice in a row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/602824/35864) ([BibLaTeX Colors And Links Only The Year Not The Rest Of The Citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536353/35864)), [Inconsistent bracket color with citet and citep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425283/35864)

Comment: Thank you for the satisfying answer @moewe!